# Parse Push Notification Remove Scheduled Push

Tags: javascript, android, parse-platform, push-notification

I have scheduled a parse push notification using cloud code. Now is there a way

1. change the date/time of that notification.
2. remove this notification from schedule.

```
     var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
        query.equalTo('group_id', 'xxx');

        Parse.Push.send({
          where: query,
          data: {
            alert: "You previously created a reminder for the game today"
          },
          push_time: new Date(2014, 12, 30)
        }, {
          success: function() {
            // Push was successful
          },
          error: function(error) {
            // Handle error
          }
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There currently is *NO* API methods for this. I will update my answer when any major updates to their SDK have been published.

A work around is schedule a local push notification within Apples/Googles allowance and alter it thereafter when necessary.

Conversely,

Another way you could do it but will be code heavy; but create a push notification class on Parse Backend. Have pointers to users and create a few columns, one specifically will be a Parse Date with the proposed notification time. Update when necessary through the users device actions that way your not locked down to the one notification method set in stone. Everything is handled via cloud.

Comment: I am interested in the method you proposed in your last paragraph. As I understand it, you are suggesting creating normal Parse objects that represent push notifications. How do we get these Parse objects to behave like push notifications? Is there a way to make a Parse notification timestamp dependant on a Parse object's property?

Comment: Not quiet. I'm suggesting creating a class or however you want to do it. It doesn't have to be a class. The jist of it would be store an NSDate for the notification fire date in the backend. That way you could query it update it with ease. Then fire a LOCAL Notification based on that date

Comment: Local notifications can be canceled at any time @golddove that's the workaround I would do.

Comment: What do u mean by storing the NSDate on the backend? Is this different from storing a date as a property of a ParseObject? Also, how exactly do you "fire a LOCAL Notification based on that date"?

Comment: Not it's not different. That's what I'm referencing. And firing a local notification is simple. I'm sure if you googled it thousands of answers would pop up. It's how alarms are set. But you could use it in this case and cancel it at any time based on the users needs @golddove

Comment: I know I can set a local notification based on the time on the Parse object. However, this would be static. For example, if I change the Parse time from a different device, the local notification on the original device would still happen at the old scheduled time. Is there a workaround for that?