# Scheduling and canceling push notifications for iOS via Parse

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification, parse-cloud-code

I have an iOS app integrated with Parse.com in which I want to schedule push notifications for certain dates/times. I am storing a push notification time on PFInstallation objects for users who have an upcoming event.  I have a scheduled job running on Parse CloudCode that queries for push notification times that need to be sent within the next minute.  **Is this a good way to architect this?  If so, how can I send this push?**  `Parse.Push` takes a query for it's `where` field, but queries only return up to 1000 results which doesn't scale at all for a free app. Thus, I'm trying to use `Parse.query.each()` which has an unlimited number of results. However, now I'm unsure how to send a push to each installation this way?  Do I need to create another query within my `each()` statement?  That seems redundant and inefficient.

(Note that the push notification is a silent notification with the content-available flag set so local notifications are not an option.  Also the notifications can be cancelled by the user so scheduling the notification with the CloudCode push schedule API is not an option since [those pushes can't be cancelled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27641312/parse-push-notification-remove-scheduled-push).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say, you store push notifications time on the respective `PFInstallation` object to circumvent the lack of support for canceling a push notification through Parse, great. We'll call that column `ScheduledPushDate`; That's the easy part; +1. The part you want to accomplish is actually scheduling a push notification using the given date. Great. Another easy part; +1. The hard part is doing it the way you want; -2. `Parse.Push` is not only limited by the `where` field. A lot of variables come into play when sending a push, for example, Parse doesn't even consider any objects that don't have a valid `deviceToken` so you can omit those objects immediately. The problem your running into is not the push itself, its not how to query for validation, its simply comes down to canceling it. Sure you can always change the date in `ScheduledPushDate` to be something in the year 2025 or simply negating it altogether, but that doesn't matter because you've already given the notification a scheduled date with the payload. Keeping it simple, and according to your target (you tagged iOS, so this is an answer specifically to client-side resources since you don't want to use local notifications or cloud code) you won't be able to cancel it, because within the guidelines given, you can only construct a push notification so many ways with Parse (client-side, cloud code, dashboard), and as of right now, only one of those options allows a successful means to cancel the process, and it's through the dashboard/console.

Lets say you do it the way you are thinking about:

- Execute scheduled job to search for push times that need be fired within the coming minute. What is a "coming minute". Lets say a users time is 11:35.46 (11am35m46sec) and they want to cancel the scheduled notification and cancelled it at that moment, but your job fired at 11:35.00? Realistically, how often will that happen, not many, but it will happen and can happen. You should always code for every circumstance a user will encounter, not just the ones you want to prevent.
- Additionally, you would be exhausting almost all of your API request limits if you do have a scaleable app as mentioned.
- Lastly, to answer your question, no you don't have to do an innerQuery or additional query within the `query.each` function, as it's job is to `iterate over each result of a query`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer.  Do you know of a better way to architect a cancellable push notification solution with iOS/CloudCode?

Comment: Sorry @GingerBreadMane as I stated in my answer, there is only one way to cancel a scheduled push notification (dashboard). In your case your not scheduling them your just firing them within the coming minute, so that's probably the best workaround for firing them, however when you said users can cancel them, there's no way to guarantee to cancel a _remote_ push from parse once it's fired(or in some cases _scheduled_ to fire) unless you do it from the dashboard